# How to set the default autoTips property to false for all CrossUI UI objects

Tags: javascript, web-frameworks

I updated my CrossUI framework to version 1.2 and found that autoTips property is added to the DataModel of UI. Unfortunately, this change make trouble for my web. Every UI Item has its thumbnail tip. So how can I set autoTips to false as default? To insert "setAutoTips(false)" to all of my UI objects that will drive me crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following code before any control was created:

```
xui.UI.setDftProp({
    autoTips: false
});
```

And, if you only want to block SButton's autoTips, you can use

```
xui.UI.SButton.setDftProp({
    autoTips: false
});
```

Comment: It's a bug in xui.Tips. You can update the latest code from their SVN.